# Connexion problem with my API in my Azure VM

Tags: azure, api, timeout

I am using Azure VM to host and deploy my node js API. When I try to access to my API from my browser using http://publicIP:port I have the a message saying that the site is inaccessible because [my_VM_IP_address] refuses the connexion.

I created a virtual network linked to my virtual machine, and created rules for the ports(22, 80, 3000, 1337 (node), 27017 (mongoDB)...). Here is my configuration :

[azure_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN9TV.png)

I tried to redirect port 80 to 3000 with Apache but it didn't work either and logs only show timeout error. My firewall and proxy are disabled.

Comment: EDIT : It was a problem with my API config env (should be NODE_ENV=production) and should start the API with 'npm start' instead of  'node app.js'

Answer (score 0):

There are usually 2 NSGs when you access the VM. One for the VM's network interface and the other for the subnet. Looks to me like you have only posted the NSG for the network interface here. Can you double check the NSG for the subnet and make sure pot 80 is allowed in it? For additional info : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-linux-virtual-machine-in-azure/7-manage-vm